# Changing numeral symbols for NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter, nslocale

So my scenario is basically this:  If a user has an Arabic Locale, a date is formatted into this string: ١٩‏/١٠‏/٢٠١٢ ٣:٢١ م

The numerals are Arabic and the date is ordered/formatted a certain way according to the Arabic locale/region format.  The problem is that some users might have a Locale of Arabic, but the Language set to English (because he/she might not be able to read Arabic).

Is there a way to change just the numerals to arabic, while preserving everything else in the formatter from the Locale?  That is, format that date according to the locale/region format (preserving order) but to use English numerals rather than the Arabic numerals. I don't see any way that Apple has provided us with making such a change.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone display date using a user locale but in other language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217334/iphone-display-date-using-a-user-locale-but-in-other-language)

Comment: Why dont you use conditional as if font is english do ../../.... if font is arabic ../../.... ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one of the locale identifiers that have the English numeral symbols. E.g:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE dd MMM | hh:mm a";
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar_TN"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

This will print:

```
الخميس 14 جانفي | 02:02 م
```

Comment: For a full list of dates in different locales check this:

https://gist.github.com/devinfoley/5980066

Answer (score -1):

The following post may answer your question:
[String replacement in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668228/string-replacement-in-objective-c)

```
NSString *str = @"This is a string";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"string"
                                 withString:@"duck"];
```

For each formatted date string you would call this 10 times (0,1,2,...,8,9). Maybe this will help you.

Comment: I wouldn't encourage doing that. We can at least look into changing the NSDateFormatter's locale - instead of string replacement. The issue is also with the order of the formatting itself. Right to left instead of left to right.